# How do I add a statement to check if the users email has a value of 1 in the active column?

Tags: php

I am not sure how to approach this.  I want verify that a user exist with an email in MySQL database and then verify that the email address has a certain value like 1 in the active column before they have access to a page otherwise it throws a message.  If that email is valid and has a value of 1 in the active column , then verify password and if all three passes, they have access to the page.  I have attempted the lines with the --> but I am not sure if that is the best place to put the code there or not or if I am doing it right.  I am using MYSQLI.

---

```
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email='$email'");

if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){ // User doesn't exist
$_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
header("location: error.php");
}

else {  //User exists
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();

--> //$Act = $mysqli->query("SELECT $email FROM accounts WHERE active='1'");

--> if ( !$_SESSION['active'] = 1 )
  {

    $_SESSION['message'] = "Your account has been activated and is being reviewed";
    header("location: error.php");

   }

else
if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) ) {

    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $user['last_name'];
    $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];

    // This is how we'll know the user is logged in
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

    header("location: https://somepage.php");
}
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "You have entered wrong password, try again!";
    header("location: error.php");
}
}
 }
```

Comment: Combine the initial query:`select * from accounts where email = "email" and active = 1;`

Comment: Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Your specific query is currently ok because you used escape_string and single quotes round it, but anything involving number fields is not protected by this measure.

Comment: and all `header("location:` lines will need to be followed by `die();`, otherwise the current script will still continue outputting. A normal browser will respect the redirect location header and ignore the subsequent output, but a non-browser client (e.g. a webcrawler or other bot, or a testing tool like Postman) generally does not, which potentially leaves your content exposed to invalid users.

Comment: Thanks Kisaragi and ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kisagari is right, it's better to combine the initial query and you need to secure your code against sql injection with prepared statements. 
Here an exemple on how you could improve and secure your code :

```
$email = $_POST['email']; 

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email)
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;


if ( !$result || $num_of_rows == 0 ) { 
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
    header("location: error.php");
    die();
}

$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ( $user['active'] != 1 ) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Your account has been activated and is being reviewed";
    header("location: error.php");
    die();
} 

//password verification etc
```

Comment: I like this idea but I am obtaining an error of Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference.  Line $stmt->bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);

Comment: I found this :  

Watch out! mysqli_stmt::bind_param accepts a reference to a variable, not a constant value. Therefore you have to create a variable to hold that 0 and then reference that variable instead.
$i = 0;
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $i, $victimiid);  Would this be correct?

Comment: look at the doc : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
$stmt->bind_param("ii", i, $victimiid); is not correct, $stmt->bind_param("i", $victimiid); is ok. I edited my code above

Comment: Thanks J-C Forest for your help .

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. I have given your code the basic structure you can improve it further according to your need.

```
if(empty($_SESSION) && !empty($_POST['email']))
    $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
else
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email='$email'");

if ( !$result || $result->num_rows == 0 ){ // User doesn't exist
$_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
header("location: error.php");
}

//User exists
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
if($user['active'] != 1){//not active
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
    $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Your account has been activated and is being reviewed";
    header("location: error.php");
}

if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) ) {//valid password

    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $user['last_name'];
    $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];

    // This is how we'll know the user is logged in
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

    header("location: https://somepage.php");
}
$_SESSION['message'] = "You have entered wrong password, try again!";
header("location: error.php");
```

I hope this will help.And do consider using parameterized query it will save you from sql injection.

Comment: Thanks for your input Vjay

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you to start using PDO. You can read about [here](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php). I tried to figure out what you wanted to do and wrote this simple example.

```
//receive data
$email = isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:null;
$password = isset($_POST['password'])?$_POST['password']:null;

//connect to database
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbName, $username, $password); //replace your credentials
$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = :email";
$statement = $connection->prepare($query); 
$statement->bindParam(':email',$email); //bind $email variable to ':email'
$statemnet->execute(); //execute the query
if($statement->rowCount() > 0){
  $row = $statement->fetch();
  if($row['active'])){
    //user is active
    if(password_verify($password,$row['password'])){
      //password is correct
      $location = "success.php";
      //do some staff
    }else{
      //password is incorrect
      $location = "error.php";
    }
  }else{
    //user is not active
    $location = "error.php";
  }
}else{
  //user does no exists
  $location = "error.php";
}
header("Location: ".$location);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input xepe.